# Need help with the first step in Theorem 1 of Nair's classic paper on Least Common Multiple

Tags: calculus, integration, binomial-coefficients, proof-explanation, least-common-multiple

I am now reading through M. Nair's classic [paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320934) on the lower bound of the [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple).

The first step in Theorem 1 is not obvious to me.  I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me understand why each part is true.

Here's the first step:

> Consider, for $n\ge1$, the integral:
>
> $$I = \int_0^1x^n(1-x)^n dx=\int_0^1\sum_{r=0}^{n}(-1)^r{n\choose r}x^{n+r}dx=\sum_{r=0}^n(-1)^r{n\choose r}\frac{1}{n+r+1}$$

I am confused how $r$ gets added; how the integral on the far left maps to the sum; and how the integral simplifies to the final result.

I suspect that this is straight forward calculus so I really appreciate any help.  I suspect that this will teach me a very basic principle with integrals that will be incredibly helpful to me going forward.  :-)

Comment: What's the binomial expansion of $(1-x)^n$?

Comment: Thanks!  Is that how he does it.  $(1-x)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}(-x)^{i}$.  I got it.  The last part is just substituting $1$ and $0$ for $x$.

Comment: Yes, that's it (with r for i)

Comment: Thanks.  I should have known that.  The integral was intimidating me.  Now, it is quite clear!  :-)